# Data loss when serializing with JSON

Tags: c#, json

This is the code that reproduces the problem:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static JsonSerializerSettings Setting = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var script = new SubClass();
            script.Param.Add(new Parameter()
            {
                msg = "I will die"
            });
            var obj = new Class();
            obj.subObj = script;

            string json;
            string json2;
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Setting);
            Console.WriteLine("before:");
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(json, Setting);
            json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Setting);
            Console.WriteLine("after:");
            Console.WriteLine(json2);
        }

        public class Class
        {
            public IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters => subObj?.parameters();
            public SubClass subObj { get; set; }
        }

        public class Parameter
        {
            public string msg { get; set; }
        }
        public class SubClass
        {
            public List<Parameter> Param { get; set; } = new List<Parameter>();

            public IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters()
            {
                return Param;
            }
        }
    }
```

The results of this run show that the results of the two serializations are different:

```
before:
{"$id":"1","parameters":[{"$id":"2","msg":"I will die"}],"subObj":{"$id":"3","Param":[{"$ref":"2"}]}}
after:
{"$id":"1","parameters":[null],"subObj":{"$id":"2","Param":[null]}}
```

I tried to delete the Class.parameters attribute, and the running results returned to normal. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

i've tried your code and here what I found.
If you delete

```
PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
```

the code workk just fine.
I think it's a problem of setter because if you put a break point you can see that the problem is cause by the deserialisation.
I know by experience that newtonsoft is tricky with some setter and if they are in private they're unable to be use by it.

I hope that help you